# Is ARG inside Dockerfile supported?

Tags: openshift

In Openshift 3.11, I'm trying to start a BuildConfig with a dockerStrategy and a Dockerfile.
In the Dockerfile, I would like to do something like :

```
ARG IMAGE=ubuntu
FROM $ARG
```

It is working fine in pure docker. But not in Openshift. It tries and fails to pull the image "$ARG" (not Ubuntu).

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ARG does not work in FROM in Openshift 3.11.

See discussion here https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/19483 which directs to an issue https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1801875.

It seems it will change in the near future.